# Examples of non-abelian groups with no abelian subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have been trying to find a counterexample that all groups (finite and infinite) have an abelian subgroup (besides the trivial subgroup).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21):

Every non-abelian group has a non-trivial abelian subgroup: Let $G$ be a nonabelian group and $x\in G$, $x$ not the identity. Then $\langle x\rangle$ is an abelian subgroup of $G$.

EDIT: 
In case you are curious, there are nonabelian groups such that the only abelian subgroups are the cyclic ones generated by one element. For example, $S_3$ is a nonabelian group such that only the cyclic subgroups are abelian.

Comment: Or at least "less trivial". ;)

Comment: @Ben Sheller Could you provide more examples other than S3?

Comment: @byk7 Free groups with at least two generators.

Answer (score 12):

It's impossible, as the subgroup generated by one element is cyclic and a cyclic group is abelian.